# How to avoid argparser type error when omitting argument?

Tags: r, command-line-arguments, argparse

Using `argparser` in R, I'm getting an error when specifying the type of an argument in the call to `add_argument` but not passing an argument to the script at the MacOSX command line. For example, given this R script:

```
library(argparser)
p <- arg_parser(description = "A test parser")
p <- add_argument(p, "--alpha", type = "double", help = "alpha for p-value")
p <- add_argument(p, "--sig-digits", type = "integer", help="number of significant digits")
args <- parse_args(p)
print(str(args))
```

and invoking it at the command line:

```
Rscript argparser-test.R --alpha 0.1
```

I am returned the error:

```
Error in (function (object, class, nargs)  :
Invalid argument value: expecting integer but got: (NA).
Calls: parse_args -> mapply -> <Anonymous>
```

Interestingly, there is no error if you let `--alpha` take it's default:

```
Rscript argparser-test.R
```

Returns:

```
List of 5
 $           : logi FALSE
 $ help      : logi FALSE
 $ opts      : logi NA
 $ alpha     : logi NA
 $ sig_digits: logi NA
NULL
```

Notice the `NA` value here for `sig_digits` is type `logical`, not `integer`, as defined in the `add_argument` function.

Am I doing something wrong here? In the mean time, I suppose I will get around this by making the default `--sig-digits` = -1, then handling that as an exception, but I'd prefer not to.

Update: Actually, -1 throws the same error, which is very frustrating because I want to use a number for the exception that non-sensical. 9999 works, and is unlikely to be input by the user, but actually it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this error a month back or so. This is a problem with how optional arguments are parsed by the `argparser` package. Basically it does respect the order of optional arguments as it should in every situation, and sometimes it thus expects the wrong argument type.

I've opened an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/djhshih/argparser/issues/25/unexpected-behaviour-for-optional) on the package [`bitbucket`](https://bitbucket.org/djhshih/argparser) page. I highly suggest upvoting this and adding a comment to help adding to the attention of the issue.

In my issue I provided a possible solution to the problem which amounts to changing `parse_args` to the following definition (one could pull and recreate the package with this function at which point it would [should] work as expected)

```
parse_args <- function (parser, argv = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)) 
{
    stopifnot(is(parser, "arg.parser"))
    values <- list()
    argv <- preprocess_argv(argv, parser)
    arg.flags <- parser$args[parser$is.flag]
    x <- as.logical(parser$defaults[parser$is.flag])
    x[is.na(x)] <- FALSE
    names(x) <- sub("^-+", "", arg.flags)
    flag.idx <- match(arg.flags, argv)
    flag.idx <- flag.idx[!is.na(flag.idx)]
    if (length(flag.idx) > 0) {
        x[match(argv[flag.idx], arg.flags)] <- TRUE
        argv <- argv[-flag.idx]
    }
    values <- c(values, x)
    if (values$help) {
        print(parser)
        quit()
    }
    x <- parser$defaults[parser$is.opt.arg]
    arg.opt <- parser$args[parser$is.opt.arg]
    names(x) <- sub("^-+", "", arg.opt)
    i <- match("--opts", argv)
    if (!is.na(i)) {
        opts <- readRDS(argv[i + 1])
        opts <- opts[!names(opts) %in% c("opts", "help")]
        idx <- match(sanitize_arg_names(names(opts)), sanitize_arg_names(names(x)))
        if (any(is.na(idx))) {
            stop("Extra arguments supplied in OPTS file: (", 
                paste(setdiff(names(opts), names(x)), collapse = ", "), 
                ").")
        }
        x[idx] <- opts
    }
    arg.idx <- match(arg.opt, argv)
    arg.idx <- arg.idx[!is.na(arg.idx)]
    arg.opt.types <- parser$types[parser$is.opt.arg]
    arg.opt.nargs <- parser$nargs[parser$is.opt.arg]
    ###               ###
    ## Altered section ##
    ###               ###
    if (length(arg.idx) > 0) {
        # extract values following the optional argument label
        x[ind <- match(argv[arg.idx], arg.opt)] <- argv[arg.idx+1];
        # convert type of extraced values; x is now a list
        x[ind] <- mapply(convert_type,                                
                         object = x[ind], 
                         class = arg.opt.types[ind], 
                         nargs = arg.opt.nargs[ind], 
                         SIMPLIFY = FALSE);                                    
        # remove extracted arguments
        to.remove <- c(arg.idx, arg.idx+1);
        argv <- argv[-to.remove];
    }
    ###               ###
    ## Altered section ##
    ###               ###
    values <- c(values, x)
    x <- argv
    args.req <- parser$args[parser$is.req.arg]
    args.req.types <- parser$types[parser$is.req.arg]
    args.req.nargs <- parser$nargs[parser$is.req.arg]
    if (length(x) < length(args.req)) {
        print(parser)
        stop(sprintf("Missing required arguments: expecting %d values but got %d values: (%s).", 
            length(args.req), length(x), paste(x, collapse = ", ")))
    }
    else if (length(x) > length(args.req)) {
        print(parser)
        stop(sprintf("Extra arguments supplied: expecting %d values but got %d values: (%s).", 
            length(args.req), length(x), paste(x, collapse = ", ")))
    }
    else if (length(args.req) > 0) {
        names(x) <- args.req
        x <- mapply(convert_type, object = x, class = args.req.types, 
            nargs = args.req.nargs, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    }
    values <- c(values, x)
    names(values) <- sanitize_arg_names(names(values))
    values
}
```

Comment: `Error in preprocess_argv(argv, parser) :
  could not find function "preprocess_argv"`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  The function calls several functions within the `argparser` environment, and these may not be "attached" (eg: you can see them using `argparser:::preprocess_argv`. To use it without downloading and repackaging the function do: 1) Execute the function, to get errors as above. 2) For every error use search and replace for the function mentioned in the error and replace with with `argparser:::[name of function that gives error]`. At some point it hopefuly stops giving errors. I tested it by doing just that my alteration didn't break the function.

Comment: bingo! all fixed, thanks so much for doing and sharing this work.

Comment: My pleasure. It does seem like the author of the package is not very interested in this package. I considered extending and pushing a `argparser2020` package to cran, but I've decided to give the author **djhshih** some time before doing so.

Comment: Another thing, `argparser` parses multi-value arguments to a comma separated string, rather than a list as with `argparse`. Much less good, right?

Comment: Could you come with an example? I honestly haven't explored this avenue, but it sounds like an easy fix as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218774/discussion-between-oliver-and-tim-farkas).